# How to write Independency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I have been searching and trying to fix this the last couple of days. As I am new to .net/core/c# this is a bit confusing to me. (I am used to PHP)
After searching on my error I have found out that it is probably the dependency injection I miss in my code. So I have been trying to insert it different places without luck.

Here I have a .net core web application MVC project where I have been trying to add a WebApi to my project. I have understood that in .net Core webapi and mvc are supposed to work better together.
After reading this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1, I did not understand if I was supposed to create a new class for all Controllers, or if I am supposed to have one class for all controllers, or actually where to put it. Should I put it inside ArticlesController.cs?

**So as the Arcticles controller is the simples controller I have. How do i write the dependency injection for it? Should I write it in to a new class or an existing class?**

**startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EducFinder
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddAutoMapper();

            //services.AddTransient<MyService>();
            //services.AddTransient<MyHelper>();
            services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AdminConnectionstring")));//add
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            //services.AddControllers();
            //services.AddScoped<IMyArticles, MemoryRepository>();
            //services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(op => op.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AdminConnectionstring")));//add
           
            //services.AddScoped<IRepository, MemoRepostory>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                //endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "api", pattern: "api/{controller}/{id?}");
                //endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "api", pattern: "api/{controller=Admin}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Articles.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace EducFinder.Models
{
    
    public partial class Articles 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public DateTime Createdon { get; set; }
        public string Active { get; set; }
        public int? Userid { get; set; }
        public virtual Users User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ArticlesController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EducFinder.Models;

namespace EducFinder.api
{
    
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ArticlesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context _context;

        public ArticlesController(DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Articles
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Articles>>> GetArticles()
        {
            return await _context.Articles.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Articles/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Articles>> GetArticles(int id)
        {
            var articles = await _context.Articles.FindAsync(id);

            if (articles == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return articles;
        }

        // PUT: api/Articles/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutArticles(int id, Articles articles)
        {
            if (id != articles.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(articles).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ArticlesExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Articles
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Articles>> PostArticles(Articles articles)
        {
            _context.Articles.Add(articles);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetArticles", new { id = articles.Id }, articles);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Articles/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Articles>> DeleteArticles(int id)
        {
            var articles = await _context.Articles.FindAsync(id);
            if (articles == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Articles.Remove(articles);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return articles;
        }

        private bool ArticlesExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Articles.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

namespace EducFinder.Models
{
    public partial class DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context : DbContext
    {
    public DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context()
    {
    }

    public DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context(DbContextOptions<DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Articles> Articles { get; set; }
//...more code
    public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=cool.com;Initial Catalog=DB_Coolstuff;User Id=DB_CoolStuff_admin;Password=IDidNotForgetMyPassword;");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Articles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Active)
                .HasColumnName("active")
                .HasMaxLength(1)
                .IsFixedLength();

            entity.Property(e => e.Createdon)
                .HasColumnName("createdon")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.Summary)
                .HasColumnName("summary")
                .HasColumnType("text");

            entity.Property(e => e.Title)
                .HasColumnName("title")
                .HasMaxLength(60)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Userid).HasColumnName("userid");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                .WithMany(p => p.Articles)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.Userid)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Articles_Users");
        });

        //... Much more code

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Active)
                .HasColumnName("active")
                .HasMaxLength(1)
                .IsFixedLength();

            entity.Property(e => e.Createdon)
                .HasColumnName("createdon")
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                .HasColumnName("email")
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Fbtoken)
                .HasColumnName("fbtoken")
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.Fbuserid)
                .HasColumnName("fbuserid")
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Feideuserid)
                .HasColumnName("feideuserid")
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Guserid)
                .HasColumnName("guserid")
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Modifiedon)
                .HasColumnName("modifiedon")
                .HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .HasColumnName("name")
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Password)
                .HasColumnName("password")
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Salt)
                .HasColumnName("salt")
                .HasMaxLength(100)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Securityrole)
                .HasColumnName("securityrole")
                .HasMaxLength(1)
                .IsFixedLength();
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
}
```

When I try to access the WebAPi I get this error:
[image: Error message when accessing WebAPI]

Comment: So what’s your question? Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, I dont get any other error. Well, I get an error when I put dependency Injection the wrong place. But as I have written in bold text, I dont know where to put the dependency injection. Should it be in a new class or an existing class?

Comment: you have implemented it correctly, I dont see any issue. You can also use in thie way. `using (var context = serviceProvider.GetService<YourDbContext>())
{
  ...
}`

Comment: @viveknuna I think we are closing in to something now. Because I get a error with GetService.Because I get the error: _Iservicecollection does not contain a definition for getservice_

I have added NuGet: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection. But still get this eroor with GetService...

Comment: Your question title is a lot ore interesting than the post.

Comment: Thats the weirdest name I ever seen `DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context`.

Comment: @TaW - Thats the problem when you dont know what is wrong and you dont get an error.

Comment: @LegacyCode Thank you:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never register `DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context` in `ConfigureServices`. There's just an `AddDbContext` call with the base class `DbContext` as generic type argument. Instead you should add your own `DbContext`(s) there:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // More stuff here.
    services.AddDbContext<DB_A64E0D_yiyote3945Context>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AdminConnectionstring")));
    // ...
}
```

**Short excursion on generics as requested:**

When writing a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) function, class, etc. you basically write a blueprint. Later on when using that blueprint you have to supply the actual `Type` that you want to use with this blueprint. That is your [generic type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters). E.g. the [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) class has one generic type parameter called `T`. At [runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-in-the-run-time) a specified class is generated for each different type provided as type parameter. So for each of `List<int>` and `List<string>` the runtime generates the appropriate code to run from the blueprint `List<T>`. The same applies to methods like `AddDbContext<TContext>`. For each `TContext` a specialized version is generated.

That's the very short version for generics, but it should at least give you the basics. If you know `C++` you might want to compare it to `template`s, but that's actually a different thing (but again might give you some clue what's going on)